# Tensorflow LinearRegressor evaluate method hangs

Tags: tensorflow

Consider the following toy TensorFlow code. The *fit* method of *LinearRegressor* works properly and finds the right coefficients (i.e. y = x1 + x2), but *evaluate* (see the last print statement) hangs. Any idea what's wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf

x1 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, -1, -3]
x2 = [5, 2, 1, 5, 0, 2, 4, 2]
y = [6, 5,5, 10, 1, 8, 3, -1]

def train_fn():
  return {'x1': tf.constant(x1), 'x2':tf.constant(x2)}, tf.constant(y)


features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('x1', dimension=1),
            tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('x2', dimension=1)]
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)
estimator.fit(input_fn=train_fn, steps=10000)

for vn in estimator.get_variable_names():
  print('variable name', vn, estimator.get_variable_value(vn))
print(estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_fn))
```

Answer (score 4):

`estimator.evaluate()` takes a parameter `steps`, which defaults to `None`, which is interpreted as "infinity". It therefore never ends.

To make it end, pass `steps=1` explicitly:

```
estimator.evaluate(input_fn=your_input_fn, steps=1)
```

Comment: More specifically, the documentation says that if steps is `None`, then it will evaluate steps until `input_fn` raises an end-of-input exception.